# How to Display Image which is stored on the server referenced through MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have a form which lets users upload an image in PHP, and the image is then stored in a file located in my root folder called 'avatars', but it is referenced in my main MySQL table - this is the processing bit in my php.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["clogo"]["tmp_name"],
"avatars/" . $_FILES["clogo"]["name"]);
```

What i want to do is display this image next to the relevant entry but i'm having difficulty with it. Below is how i am displaying other information from the table (having performed the query to that table and stored everything in $rsjobinfo)

```
<li id = "compname"><?php echo $rsjobinfo['company_name'];?></li>
```

I was trying this but its obviously wrong!

```
<img src = "avatars/" <?php echo $rsjobinfo['clogo'];?>/>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: You will be able to retrieve the image name if you saved it somewhere in the db. It doesn't seem to have happened.

Comment: Dan, the image src tag is just a path from the current page to the image.  What error are you getting?  If the page is loading, what does View source on the page say?  Is this in a virtual directory on the server, if so your path may not be correct.

Comment: Are you sure you save the `$_FILES["clogo"]["name"]` as the `clogo` in the database???

Comment: Hopefully you're checking for collisions in the filenames, otherwise two people uploading images with the same name are going to be sharing the last upload's avatar.

Comment: @David C 'What does view source say?' Thanks David, i had the path wrong -i'm an idiot. Sorry for wasting your and everyone's time! Changed to <img src = "http://localhost/mdj/avatars/<?php echo $rsjobinfo['clogo'];?>"/> and it works. Thanks again

Comment: @Marc B I will do Mark, but at the moment i'm just trying to get everything working. Thanks for the tip, Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting url outside of quotation marks.

Should be just

```
<img src = "avatars/<?php echo $rsjobinfo['clogo'];?>"/>
```

assuming  $rsjobinfo['clogo'] returns the correct file name.

Comment: @AR Thanks AR, i got it by looking at the source - see my comment above - yeah, this isn't my proudest moment!